# Move item doesn't work in MS Graph API for onedrive

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm following the instructions https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_move to move a file to a new folder through the REST api and it doesn't work. THe URL I use are

"/drive/items/014LYBHNMWA5UQYF4QGRFZDOTYFZEUTXZX" and "/me/drive/items/014LYBHNMWA5UQYF4QGRFZDOTYFZEUTXZX". The body of the request is

```
{"parentReference" : {"id": "014LYBHNOQBL7MB23DNVGJP355BSMQOLTY"}}
```

I get the following error with either URI. What am I doing wrong?

```
[{
  "error": {
    "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
    "message": "The parameter parentReference does not exist in method GetById.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "3d569cf4-799c-47e0-918a-3fbb30e7a13c",
      "date": "2016-02-25T15:25:54"
    }
  }
}
, 400, Bad Request]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this error is returned when you attempt to `POST` instead of `PATCH`.

Comment: thank you @brad. Its correct my http client doesn't support PATCH (not many do). I use URLConnection in jdk 1.7. But I found a work around that I can do a POST with the following http header and it should be fine. "X-HTTP-Method-Override: PATCH Is this not supported? Does have to be an actual PATCH request?

Comment: Give `X-HTTP-Method` a go instead and see if that works

Comment: I got this working by using httppatch from org.apache.commons.httpclient 4.5 libraries. httpurlconnection with above work around didn't work